# Point Distances to many buffer zones

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join, proximity

Here is my problem:

I have 72 points, and each one of those points falls within multiple 1,000 foot buffers zones. I am trying to find out the distance from the point that falls within a buffer to the centroid of that buffer for each point

I have performed an intersect between the buffer zones and the 72 points so I know every buffer zone a point falls into. there are 441 instances a point intersects a buffer, and I did a summarize count for each point Name and joined it to the intersect FC. I also Did a select by location and there are 371 buffer zones that intersect the points. 
so 441 intersected instances for points, and 371 buffer zones (Different points, in the same buffer problem)

What is confusing me is the relationship between the two. I have used the generate a near table using the centroids of the 371 bufferzones to the 72 points. But my output was 371...

My input for the near table is the buffer centroids, because i need to specify 1000 foot radius, and my near features are the 72 points.

Should i try a spatial join, or the near tool? I do not think I am understanding the cardinality relationship and am getting really confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the X/Y locations of the 441 points, and the X/Ys of the buffers they are within in a single table, or create a single table as such, you can use the X/Y to line tool. The X/Y to line tool will include a LENGTH_GEO field with the length of the line between the two, therefore the distance, in the unit of whichever projection you are using.